# Oracle XMLAGG issue with combining cells that have comma separated values in cells

Tags: oracle, csv

Have a situation where I'm trying to use xmlagg to get:

```
     | ID | name
row1 | 1  | apple
row2 | 1  | apple,pear,banana
row3 | 1  | apple,banana
row4 | 1  | pear,banana,orange
row5 | 2  | orange
row6 | 2  | orange,pear
row7 | 2  | pear, banana
```

to:

```
1 | apple,pear,banana,orange
2 | orange,pear,banana
```

Is this possible using xmlagg?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data:

```
select * from t_ ;

C1   C2   C3
row1 1    apple
row2 1    apple,pear,banana
row3 1    apple,banana
row4 1    pear,banana,orange
row5 2    orange
row6 2    orange,pear
row7 2    pear,banana
```

Query:

```
select 
c2 ||' | '|| rtrim ( 
   xmlagg( xmlelement( e, c3 || ',' ) ).extract('//text()')
, ','
) result
from
  (
    select distinct c2, regexp_substr(c3,'[^,]+', 1, level ) c3 from t_
    connect by regexp_substr(c3, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  )
group by c2
;

RESULT
1 | apple,pear,orange,banana
2 | pear,orange,banana
```

LISTAGG() may also work -

```
select 
c2 ||' | '|| rtrim ( 
   listagg(c2 , ',') within group ( order by c2 )
) result
from
  (
    select distinct c2, regexp_substr(c3,'[^,]+', 1, level ) c3 from t_
    connect by regexp_substr(c3, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  )
group by c2
;

RESULT
1 | apple,banana,orange,pear
2 | banana,orange,pear
```

Dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0f83509b40ed353efee9b9b8bb8acd58).

Comment: @pgfitzpatrick - You are very welcome!